# How do I kill my thread on python script exit(If I need to)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm developing a program that fetches data from an API every second. So I have a function called tick which basically returns data from the API. In order to be able to use the GUI without freezing every second while waiting for the response, I put it on a thread, like this:

```
def every(delay, task):
  next_time = time.time() + delay
  while True:
    time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
    try:
      task()
    except Exception:
      traceback.print_exc()
      # in production code you might want to have this instead of course:
      # logger.exception("Problem while executing repetitive task.")
    # skip tasks if we are behind schedule:
    next_time += (time.time() - next_time) // delay * delay + delay

    ...
    ...

threading.Thread(target=lambda: every(1, tick)).start()

window.mainloop()
```

When I close the GUI window, the python console goes crazy like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 22, in every
>       task()   File "D:/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 66, in tick
>       insert_text(unn1, unn_text)   File "D:/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 47, in insert_text
>       entry.delete(0, END)   File "D:\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2676, in delete
>       self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last) RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

It is clear to me that the thread isn't terminating. But I'm new to python and threading so I don't know if this thread needs to be closed from the code or if when I'm actually running the compiled program it will automatically close it when I close the program window. So, do I need to close it from within? If so, how do I do it the right way?

Comment: use `running = True ; while running:` instead of `while True` and set `running=False` when you end script. And wait for `process.join()` but you have to use `process = Thread(...)` and `process.start()`

Comment: instead of `lambda` you can do `Thread(every,  (1, tick))`. `Thread` uses function's name as first argument and tuple `(1, tick)` as second argument and it will use this tuple as arguments for `every` when it starts `every`

Comment: When you close de window, you kills the main process. Also, there's no way out of the `while True` loop

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco when close window then it exits `window.mainloop()` and you can still execute some code after `window.mainloop()`. you can set `running = False` to stop `while running`. You can also wait for end of thread using `thread.join()`

Comment: @furas being new to python, your answer is a little hard to understand because I'm very newbie. But I'll do my research on that

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco so I really need to kill the thread on window close, right? How to set running = false when the window closes?

Comment: if task is short running function then you could use `after(time, task)` instead of thread and `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global variable (ie. `running`) to control `while` loop.

After that you can also use `thread.join()` to wait for end of thread.

```
def every(delay, task):
  global running 

  next_time = time.time() + delay

  while running:
      ...
      ...

#---------------------------------------------

running = True
thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: every(1, tick))
thread.start()

window.mainloop()

running = False # it will end `while` loop
thread.join()   # it will wait for end of thread
```

---

If `task` doesn't get long time then you could use `after()` instead of thread and `while` loop. Something similar to

```
def every(delay, task):
    start = time.time()

    try:
       task()
    except Exception:
       traceback.print_exc()

    end = time.time()
    diff = end - start
    after_time = max(0, delay - diff)

    if running:
        window.after(after_time, every, (1000, task)) # 1000ms=1s

#---------------------------------------------

running = True

window.every(1000, tick) # 1000ms=1s
window.mainloop()

running = False # it will end `while` loop
```

Comment: It worked, although the error shows 1 time before exiting successfully